# Image not fit in div and When we do ctrl+shift+m all information and images are out of all divs and merged.d

Tags: css

**HTML CODE**

```
<body>
<div id="main">
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-content left">
        <img src="sydney.jpg" />
        <h3>Sydney</h3>
        <p>djadijoi djoiqj eqoijweoq eijqoeiqoeqeqe jeoiqe qeqoejqeqe qeuqqueqie qeqe qe</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content left">
        <img src="sydney.jpg" />
        <div class="box-info">
            <h3>Sydney</h3>
            <p>djadijoi djoiqj eqoijweoq eijqoeiqoeqeqe jeoiqe qeqoejqeqe qeuqqueqie qeqe qe</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
#main{
 width:100%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 }
 #main .box{
 border:1px solid red;
 }
 #main .box .box-content{
 border: 1px solid green;
 width:25%
 }
 #main .box .box-content img{
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 }
 .left{
 float:left;
 }
 .clear{
 clear: both;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You set a fix `width`to your images.

**CSS**

```
#main .box .box-content img{ 
  height: 200px; 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Now it fits perfectly to your `<div class="box-content">` [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/znLsj0qh/)